# VS 2022 Publish Azure Function to Container Apps

Tags: azure-functions, visual-studio-2022, azure-container-apps

Bear with me for this noob question but I am just starting to look into Container Apps.

How come I can deploy a .NET Web Api project from just by right-clicking and choosing Publish and then I'm able to see Container Apps:

[image]

If I do the same thing on an C# Azure Function, I don't get the option to Publish to Container Apps:

[image]

Is this a matter of some tooling support or something conceptual I don't understand? I have the latest VS 2022 "Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (3) (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.2.4"

Answer (score 0):

While you create the Function App in a Docker Container through Azure Portal, it shows

> Linux is the only supported Operating System for your selection of runtime stack.

I have Created one function app in docker container.
[image]

In Locally, add the [Docker Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/overview?view=vs-2022) while creating Function is VS 2022:

[image]

You can see the same option Azure Container Apps (Linux) from .NET Web API Publish option for the Azure Function Project also in VS 2022 as the one I have created and shown in above Screenshot:

[image: AzureContainerApps]

You can publish to any external docker container registry using the below option from Visual Studio 2022:

[image: ExternalDockerContainer]